# Create subtotal and total amount with jquery based on input text qty

Tags: javascript, jquery

actually how to automatically calculate the 'subtotal'and 'Total Amount' based on qty ( input boxes ) that had a spinner, i am new to js with calculate function, so any advice will be appreciated

Thanks

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/m6csdx51/)

```
<div class="table-responsive" id="bottom-table">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>No</th>
                  <th>Part Number</th>
                  <th>Desc</th>
                  <th>Qty / Unit</th>
                  <th>Qty Needed</th>
                  <th>Het ( Rp )</th>
                  <th>Estimation Price</th>
                  <th>&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                 <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>3DCam01</td>
                  <td>3D Camera</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td><input class="spinner" value="1" readonly="readonly"></td>
                  <td>$1500.00</td>
                      <td><p class="subtotal"></p>Subtotal</td>
                  <td><a href="index.php?action=remove&code=3DCam01" class="btnRemoveAction">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>USB02</td>
                  <td>External Hard Drive</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td><input class="spinner" value="1" readonly="readonly"></td>
                  <td>$800.00</td>
                  <td>Subtotal</td>
                  <td><a href="index.php?action=remove&code=USB02" class="btnRemoveAction">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>wristWear03</td>
                  <td>Wrist Watch</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td><input class="spinner" value="1" readonly="readonly"></td>
                  <td>$300.00</td>
                  <td>Subtotal</td>
                  <td><a href="index.php?action=remove&code=wristWear03" class="btnRemoveAction">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>

                                           <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>Total</td>
                  <td>Total Amount</td>
                  <td><a href="index.php?action=remove&code=wristWear03" class="btnRemoveAction">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>

              </tbody>
            </table>
                      </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Hint : Start with `$("input.spinner").on("change", function(){ console.log($(this).val()) })`

Comment: Hi @dharmang, not yet, but mind about jquery calc plugin, but i need a simple code, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your fiddle. I added classes to subtotal and prices and use the stop method of spinner to validate it after the value has been changed, look on

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/m6csdx51/5/)

here is the stop function:

```
$( ".spinner" ).spinner({
min: 1,
stop: function(event, ui) {
    var _parent = $(this).closest('tr');
    var _price = _parent.find('.price').text().replace('$', '');
    _parent.find('.subtotal').html('$' + (_price * $(this).val()));
    var _total = 0;
    $( ".subtotal" ).each( function() {
        var _thisSub = $(this).text().replace('$', '');
        if( !isNaN( _thisSub ) ) {
            _total = _total + parseInt(_thisSub);
        }
    } );
    $( "#totalAmount" ).html('$' + _total);
}});
```

**Edit:** I didn't use the change method, since it is only triggered on blur of the element which gives a delay on changing the values. Updated the code for the total, totally forgot it.

Comment: Hi thanks @yjae-daline, it's possibele to set the default to 1 x current price too ? Thanks

Comment: @JoeyTheWhale of course, by using the create event. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/m6csdx51/7/) is the updated fiddle for preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest working with the [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function to get the inputs.

get notified when changed with [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and working with 
[$(".spinner").each](http://api.jquery.com/each) to iterate rough your inputs.

further i would suggest seperating the money from the currency symbol with:

```
<td>$<span class="money">1500.00</span></td>
```

Good luck